# Javascript await sequence problem in expo-sqlite

Tags: javascript, async-await, expo

I am using react native expo to do the init data load and insert it into DB.
But seems the sequence is not my expectations.

and below is my init function

```
import { getData } from './GetData'
const db = SQLite.openDatabase('db.db') // returns Database object

const initDB = async (res: any) => {
    await db.transaction(async tx => {
        await tx.executeSql(`create table if not exists table (
            id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null,
            ...... // create db query
        )`, [], 
        () => {
            console.log("created table")
        })
        
        await tx.executeSql(insertQuery
            , res.list,
            () => {
                console.log(`inserted data success`)
            },
            (_, err): boolean | any => {
                console.log(`err: ${err}`)
            }
        )
    })
}

export const initLoading = async () => {
    const res = await getData() // get data from API
    await initDB(res)
}
```

```
await new Promise(async resolve => {
    await initLoading()
    console.log("init done")
})
```

my expected console log should be

```
created table
inserted data success
init done
```

but the result is

```
init done
created table
inserted data success
```

what thing I am doing wrong to make the sequence incorrect?

Comment: You normally don't pass callbacks to functions which you expect to return a promise

Comment: I don't see anything in [the Expo documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/#websqldatabase) to suggest those methods return promises. `await` doesn't do anything useful when used on something that isn't a promise. If Expo doesn't already offer a promise-based API, you may want to [wrap the API in a promise layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) so you can use `async` functions and `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in `db.transaction` you pass a function as argument. You dont await the function  you passed, but you await just the execution of `db.transaction`. I think the best way to fix this is to wrap `db.transaction` in a Promise and resolve it when you need it to.

```js
const initDB = async (res: any) => {
    return new Promise(async resolve => 
        await db.transaction(async tx => {
            await tx.executeSql(`create table if not exists table (
                id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT not null,
                ...... // create db query
            )`, [], 
            () => {
                console.log("created table")
            })
            
            await tx.executeSql(insertQuery
                , res.list,
                () => {
                    console.log(`inserted data success`)
                    // Resovle when the data is successful
                    resolve()
                },
                (_, err): boolean | any => {
                    console.log(`err: ${err}`)
                }
            )
        })
    )
}
```

I would recommend you to also resolve on error. Else your code get's stuck.